How to create a new MUI button variant with existing varint properties and overriding properties
I am trying to create a variant of MUI button with an existing variant properties('contained') with some overriding properties. What I mean by that, I want to create a variant with the styles with an existing Button MUI variant, but by overriding some properties.
This is my current code,
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'customButton' },
          style: {
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
            fontFamily: '"Roboto-Medium", sans-serif',
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontWeight: 500,
            letterSpacing: '0.37px',
            textAlign: 'left',
            lineHeight: '22px',
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },

However I want to override these properties with whatever styling we have for the variant 'contained'.
What I did is creted a function and then tried to access the styling from the default theme. Then use this function to create the style and use it inside the theme definition.
const baseTheme = createTheme();
const createCustomButtonStyle = (overrideProps: CSSProperties) => {
  
  const containedStyle = baseTheme.components?.MuiButton?.variants?.find(
    (variant) => (variant.props as ButtonProps)?.variant === 'contained'
  )?.style;


  // Ensure containedStyle is an object before spreading
  return {...containedStyle ,
    ...overrideProps,
  };
};

However the baseTheme.components?.MuiButton looks like an empty object, so I am stuck with this as the basetheme does not have any MuiButton field. How can I do that? I looked at lots of solutions and none actually could address the exact problem. I also noticed there is a request to allow this in upcoming MUI versions.
